# most simple way to get files on a server

Tags: linux, windows, security, file-transfer

I am on windows and my server is linux. I would like to grab files from the server automatically with a script. Maybe execute a bash script remotely as well but maybe i dont need that.

I need to connect securely and i would like some kind of password so not anyone can connect. I need to download files and i'd like to get every file in a set of folders. I do not want to download them again if they exist.

What is the easiest way to do this? i thought of creating a simple .NET site with data in App_Data (so it cant be reached from the outside) however i have a feeling an easier way exist. I'd like to do scp with a shell but i am on windows and also i am unsure how to iterate through folders and only get files that dont exist.

Comment: That's a jumbled collection of vague ideas. The first thing you need to do is work out exactly what you are trying to achieve, then ask a clear question.

Comment: I got an answer that covered all of these 'ideas'. It was a great answer too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) yet? It's scriptable, pretty easy to use, and has plenty of [documentation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/start).

Or if you're more familiar with rsync, there's a verion of that for Windows too, called [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp).

Comment: excellent, i have been using WinSCP. The scripting looks nice, i havent gone too much into it (i have code working in the console but havent put it in a script file). I notice when i sync my local copy if a file has been edit my local copy is changed. I am concerned if my server gets compromised and all my backups are corrupted this will carry the change to my local files. Is there a way to get files but not update existing files?

Comment: I figured it all out! nice!

Comment: For others, the commands i used are the below with call being available if i want to run scripts --> open user:pass@domain
synchronize local C:\path\backup /path/backup -criteria=none
exit

Answer (score 1):

FTP would work for this, but is not that secure.

A good alternative is to set up sftp.

Putty windows clients for file transfer:
http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at rsync or rsync over SSH to do that. There should be a port for Windows available. Rsync's algorithms are fast, and it won't duplicate data that already exists (only changing/copying changes so that for copies over a network, if you have, say, a 200 meg video and only a few meg had been edited, that few meg will get copied, not the whole thing).